# Typescript generics: given key K and object T, constrain the type of T[K]

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have an environment where certain objects which have an `id` property expire every "tick" and need to be recalled using `getObjectById`. I would like to implement a setter method to refresh a property of something by mapping `thing.property => getObjectById(thing.property.id)`. Ideally, I would like this method to take a thing `T` and a key `K`, where `T[K]` can be an object with an id (`HasID`) or and array of them (`HasID[]`).

I believe I'm close to a solution, but it's not quite correct yet. What I currently have is listed below (a static method on a class called `$`):

```
static refresh<T extends {[K in keyof T]: HasID}, K extends keyof T>(thing: T, key: K): void;
static refresh<T extends {[K in keyof T]: HasID[]}, K extends keyof T>(thing: T, key: K): void;
static refresh<T extends {[K in keyof T]: HasID | HasID[]}, K extends keyof T>(thing: T, key: K): void {
    if (_.isArray(thing[key])) {
        thing[key] = _.map(thing[key] as HasID[], s => getObjectById(s.id)) as HasID[];
    } else {
        thing[key] = getObjectById(thing[key].id) as HasID;
    }
}
```

For example, the desired behavior for `foo: {bar: HasID, baz: HasID[], biz: string[]}` would be:

```
$.refresh(foo, 'bar') // foo.bar = getObjectById(foo.bar.id)
$.refresh(foo, 'baz') // foo.baz = _.map(foo.baz, x=>getObjectById(x.id))
$.refresh(foo, 'biz') // error: foo.biz is not HasID or HasID[]
$.refresh(foo, 'boo') // error: 'boo' is not a key of foo
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to correctly constrain the type of `T[K]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, the problem is that not every key of `T` has to be `HasID` or `HasID[]`, only the one specified by `K`

```
class $ {
  static refresh<T extends { [P in K]: HasID }, K extends string>(thing: T, key: K): void;
  static refresh<T extends { [P in K]: HasID[] }, K extends string>(thing: T, key: K): void;
  static refresh<T extends { [P in K]: HasID | HasID[] }, K extends string>(thing: T, key: K): void {

  }
}

let foo: { bar: HasID, baz: HasID[], biz: string[] };
$.refresh(foo, 'bar') // foo.bar = getObjectById(foo.bar.id)
$.refresh(foo, 'baz') // foo.baz = _.map(foo.baz, x=>getObjectById(x.id))
$.refresh(foo, 'biz') // error: foo.biz is not HasID or HasID[]
$.refresh(foo, 'boo') // error: 'boo' is not a key of foo
```

Also instead of `{ [P in K]: HasID }` you can use `Record<K, HasId>`, I left your original version to make it easier to track the differences. Using record the sigantures would be:

```
class $ {
  static refresh<T extends Record<K, HasID>, K extends string>(thing: T, key: K): void;
  static refresh<T extends Record<K, HasID>[], K extends string>(thing: T, key: K): void;
  static refresh<T extends Record<K, HasID | HasID[]>, K extends string>(thing: T, key: K): void {

  }
}
```