# Assignment involving generic property of generic object fails to typecheck correctly within generic function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function that reads or writes the caller-chosen property of a given object. I'm using type constraints to ensure that the key passed is for a property that is assignable to or from the relevant type. Calling code appears to typecheck correctly. The usage of the object's property within the implementation does not typecheck as expected.

In this example I use boolean as the expected type. I've commented the lines that are not typechecking as expected. [You can also see this example in the typescript playground here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20KeysOfPropertiesWithType%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20We%20check%20extends%20in%20both%20directions%20to%20ensure%20assignment%20could%20be%20in%20either%20direction.%0D%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20U%20%3F%20(U%20extends%20T%5BK%5D%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never)%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20PickPropertiesWithType%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20KeysOfPropertiesWithType%3CT%2C%20U%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20booleanAssignmentTest%3CT%20extends%20PickPropertiesWithType%3CT%2C%20boolean%3E%2C%20K%20extends%20KeysOfPropertiesWithType%3CT%2C%20boolean%3E%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key%3A%20K)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo2%3A%20string%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%2C%20but%20there%20should%20be!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20%22Type%20'true'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'T%5BK%5D'.%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%20aBool%3A%20false%2C%20aNumber%3A%2033%2C%20anotherBool%3A%20false%20%7D%3B%0D%0AbooleanAssignmentTest(foo%2C%20%22aBool%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine!%0D%0AbooleanAssignmentTest(foo%2C%20%22anotherBool%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine!%0D%0AbooleanAssignmentTest(foo%2C%20%22aNumber%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20working%20as%20intended!%0D%0A)

How can I express the signature of `booleanAssignmentTest` so that the typechecker understands `obj[key]` has type `boolean`? Can it be done in a fashion that keeps the `boolean` itself generic to allow multiple such similar functions, that work with other types, to be defined uniformly?

```js
type KeysOfPropertiesWithType<T, U> = {
  // We check extends in both directions to ensure assignment could be in either direction.
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? (U extends T[K] ? K : never) : never;
}[keyof T];

type PickPropertiesWithType<T, U> = Pick<T, KeysOfPropertiesWithType<T, U>>;

function booleanAssignmentTest<T extends PickPropertiesWithType<T, boolean>, K extends KeysOfPropertiesWithType<T, boolean>>(obj: T, key: K): void {
    let foo: boolean = obj[key]; // Fine!
    let foo2: string = obj[key]; // No error, but there should be!
    obj[key] = true; // Error: "Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'."
}

let foo = { aBool: false, aNumber: 33, anotherBool: false };
booleanAssignmentTest(foo, "aBool"); // Fine!
booleanAssignmentTest(foo, "anotherBool"); // Fine!
booleanAssignmentTest(foo, "aNumber"); // Error: working as intended!
```

I'm using `tsc` Version 3.4.5 in case it's relevant.

**Update:**

I found the following answer on a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52047487/740958

I tried to apply their approach which is simpler and works a little better, however the `obj[key] = true;` statement still has the same issue.

```js
function booleanAssignmentTest2<T extends Record<K, boolean>, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): void {
    let foo: boolean = obj[key]; // Fine!
    let foo2: string = obj[key]; // Error: working as intended!
    obj[key] = true; // Error: "Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'."
}

let foo = { aBool: false, aNumber: 33, anotherBool: false };

booleanAssignmentTest2(foo, "aBool"); // Fine!
booleanAssignmentTest2(foo, "anotherBool"); // Fine!
booleanAssignmentTest2(foo, "aNumber"); // Error: working as intended!
```

[This ^^ example on TS Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20booleanAssignmentTest2%3CT%20extends%20Record%3CK%2C%20boolean%3E%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key%3A%20K)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo2%3A%20string%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20working%20as%20intended!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20%22Type%20'true'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'T%5BK%5D'.%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%20aBool%3A%20false%2C%20aNumber%3A%2033%2C%20anotherBool%3A%20false%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AbooleanAssignmentTest2(foo%2C%20%22aBool%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine!%0D%0AbooleanAssignmentTest2(foo%2C%20%22anotherBool%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine!%0D%0AbooleanAssignmentTest2(foo%2C%20%22aNumber%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20working%20as%20intended!%0D%0A)

Comment: Also possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188399/typescript-constrain-argument-of-function-to-be-a-key-of-an-object-associated-w
Specifically where user @jcalz mentions: "the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that T[K] is assignable to number in the generic case". Although my issue seems to be the opposite, in that boolean is not assignable to T[K].

Comment: I may be a bit new to this level of Typescript, but isn't it the case that 'boolean' isn't an object type, so although it has values 'true' and 'false', it doens't actually have properties representing 'true' and 'false', so you couldn't really determine if T[K] extends U or vice-versa - because it can't. Indeed, for boolean/string/number you'd have to specify instanceof one of those types. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

The first option (using `KeysOfPropertiesWithType`) does not work because typescript can't reason about conditional types that still contains unresolved type parameters (such as `T` and `K` in this example)

The second option does not work because `T extends Record<K, boolean>` means `T` can for example be `{ a: false }` which would mean the assignment `obj[key] = true` would not be valid. Generally, the fact that `T[K]` must extends a type does not mean that inside the generic function we can assign any value to it, the constraint just tells us what the minimum requirement is for the value, we don't yet know the full contract `T[K]` requires.

A solution that does work, at least for your sample code, is to not use `T` at all. It does not seem necessary in this context:

```
function booleanAssignmentTest2<K extends PropertyKey>(obj: Record<K, boolean>, key: K): void {
    let foo: boolean = obj[key]; // Fine!
    let foo2: string = obj[key]; // Error: working as intended!
    obj[key] = true; // Ok now we know T[K] is boolean
}

let foo = { aBool: false, aNumber: 33, anotherBool: false };

booleanAssignmentTest2(foo, "aBool"); // Fine!
booleanAssignmentTest2(foo, "anotherBool"); // Fine!
booleanAssignmentTest2(foo, "aNumber"); // Error: working as intended!
```

If your example is more complicated, please provide a full example, although generally the solution will be use a type assertion if you are sure the value is assignable to `T[K]`, so this is a possible solution:

```
function booleanAssignmentTest2<T extends Record<K, boolean>, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): void {
    let foo: boolean = obj[key]; // Fine!
    let foo2: string = obj[key]; // Error: working as intended!
    obj[key] = true as T[K]; // ok now
}
```