# Transform Observable of objects into object of Observables

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create a function which transforms Observable of objects (which itself are collections of observables) into object of Observables
Current implementation looks like this:

```
type Inputs = {[inputName: string]: Observable<unknown>}

export const transform = <Inp extends Inputs, Keys extends keyof Inputs>(
  inputs$: Observable<Inp>,
  inputNames: Keys[],
) => {
  const cachedSinks$ = inputs$.pipe(share())

  return inputNames.reduce((result, inpName) => {
    result[inpName] = cachedSinks$
      .pipe(switchMap(sinks => sinks[inpName]))
    return result
  },
  {} as {[K in Keys]: Inp[Keys]})
}
```

However I'm getting an error at line `result[inpName] = cachedSinks$` that `TS2322: Type 'Observable  >' is not assignable to type 'Inp[Keys]'.` and I don't understand why this is happening since `Inp[Keys]` is also an Observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the fact that T[K] must extends a type does not mean that inside the generic function we can assign any value to it, the constraint just tells us what the minimum requirement is for the value, we don't yet know the full contract T[K] requires. ([Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56425551/9369606))

Suppose we pass `transform` an instance of the following [Intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) type:

```js
type ExtendedInputs = Inputs & {
    age: number
}
```

Assinging an Observble to `result[inpName]` wouldn't be safe, since `result[inpName]` may be a number.

Taking this into account consider modifying `tranform` function to use `Input` directly rather then using Generics (as it does not seem necessary in this context), as demonstrated below:

```
export const transform = <K extends keyof Inputs>(
    inputs$: Observable<Inputs>,
    inputNames: K[],
) => {
    const cachedSinks$ = inputs$.pipe(share())

    return inputNames.reduce((result, inpName) => {
        result[inpName] = cachedSinks$.pipe(switchMap(sinks => sinks[inpName]))

        return result
    }, {} as Inputs })
}
```

**Update**

You can keep it Generic, using `type assertion` if you are sure the value is assignable to `T[K]`

```
export const transform = <T extends Inputs, K extends keyof T>
  (inputs$: Observable<T>, inputNames: K[]) => {
  const cachedSinks$ = inputs$.pipe(share())


  return inputNames.reduce((result, inpName) => {

    result[inpName] = cachedSinks$.pipe(switchMap(sinks => sinks[inpName])) as T[K]

    return result

  }, {} as T)

}
```

Optionally (again,  use this option only if you are sure the value is assignable to `T[K]`)

```
 export const transform = <T extends Inputs, K extends keyof T>
   (inputs$: Observable<T>, inputNames: K[]) => {
   const cachedSinks$ = inputs$.pipe(share())
 
   return inputNames
     .reduce((result, inpName) => ({ ...result, [inpName]: cachedSinks$.pipe(switchMap(sinks => sinks[inpName])) }), {})
 }
```

Comment: looks like type assertion would be the best solution here, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
type Inputs = {[inputName: string]: Observable<unknown>}

export const transform = <Inp extends Inputs, Keys extends keyof Inputs>(
  inputs$: Observable<Inp>,
  inputNames: Keys[],
)
```

The critical part here is `Keys extends keyof Inputs`. Inputs is a type, from which you don't know any specific key. I believe you mean Inp, the type which was provided to the function. Try

```
type Inputs = {[inputName: string]: Observable<unknown>}

export const transform = <Inp extends Inputs, Keys extends keyof Inp>(
  inputs$: Observable<Inp>,
  inputNames: Keys[],
)
```

Comment: You are right, I made 2 mistakes, now it is working correctly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 mistakes in type definitions, now it is working correctly
1 mistake: `{} as {[K in Keys]: Inp[Keys]})` should be `{} as {[K in Keys]: Inp[K]})`
2 mistake: `<Inp extends Inputs, Keys extends keyof Inputs>` should be `<Inp extends Inputs, Keys extends keyof Inp>`

Comment: Are you sure it's working? you don't have any errors?

Comment: The following code shouldn't work: ` type Inputs = {[inputName: string]: Observable<unknown>}

export const transform = <Inp extends Inputs, Keys extends keyof Inp>(
  inputs$: Observable<Inp>,
  inputNames: Keys[],
) => {
    const cachedSinks$ = inputs$.pipe(share())
  
    return inputNames.reduce((result, inpName) => {
      result[inpName] = cachedSinks$
        .pipe(switchMap(sinks => sinks[inpName]))
      return result
    },
    {} as {[K in Keys]: Inp[K]})
  }`

Comment: @RafiHenig, you are right, problem still persists, I can't use Inputs directly since it is supposed to be a generic utility